# Tool for monitoring I2C bus in Windows system

Tags: windows, i2c, analyzer, traffic, bus

Are there any software applications that operate similar to USBLyzer or WireShark for monitoring I2C (HID) transactions on the system's I2C bus? If not, are there any known APIs for accessing this low-level traffic if I wanted to roll my own solution?

NOTE: connecting an external device like a logic analyzer is hugely impractical (that is my current method)

Comment: I have found this article: https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Bus_snooping/sniffing#i2c  
It describes a sniffing procedure in Linux.
Did not found yet for Windows OS.